# How to install Python libraries/packages and ibm_db 2.0.7 installation instructions?

Tags: python, windows, db2

I downloaded Python 3.6 from Python's website (from the download page for Windows) and it seems only the interpreter is available. I don't see anything else (Standard Library or something) in my system. Is it included in the interpreter and hidden or something?

I tried to install ibm_db 2.0.7 as an extension of Python DB API, but the installation instructions seem too old. The paths defined don't exist in my Win10.

By the way, I installed the latest Platform SDK as instructed (which is the predecessor of Windows 10 SDK, so I had to to install Windows 10 SDK instead). I also installed .NET SDK V1.1, which is told to include Visual C++ 2003 (Visual C++ 2003 is not available today on its own). I considered to install VS2017, but because it was too big  (12.some GB) I passed on that option.

I am stuck and can't proceed for I don't know which changes happened from the point the installation instructions have been written and what else I need to do. How can I install python with the ibm_db package on Windows 10?

Comment: Depending on what option you chosed during installation, python files might be placed in different locations. I think that by default they are in `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python`

Comment: Thank you, on your comment i checked and saw just at the location you said:)

Answer (score 0):

for python libraries you can always use pip, which is a python package installer.
if you are using python 3.6 then you already have pip. just make sure you're using pip from the main command line not the python terminal

Comment: Mohammed thank you very much, to find out what you said I have spent an hour or so, we should have come across a little bit earlier:)) BTW i also learned over the hard way that ibm_db group doesnt support Python 3.5+ yet as of now, June.2017, and i use 3.6.1.. look at this (or whoever gets interested in may take alook): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ibm_db/6-sOpk4zkCU

Answer (score 0):

ibm_db does not support Python 3.6 you need to downgrade to Python 3.5.4. That is how i did it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

pip install "ibm_db==2.0.8a"

I'm running windows 7 x64, Python 3.6.

```
(.env) C:\Users\139206494\Documents\aap2>pip install "ibm_db==2.0.8a"
Collecting ibm_db==2.0.8a
  Downloading ibm_db-2.0.8a.tar.gz (689kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 696kB 10.2MB/s
Building wheels for collected packages: ibm-db
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for ibm-db ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\139206494\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\48\d4\4
6\5d70bcb4752142099244036fdfeaf04bf5e51f102c363e42e7
Successfully built ibm-db
Installing collected packages: ibm-db
Successfully installed ibm-db-2.0.8a0
```

Answer (score 0):

For python 3.6 try:

pip install "ibm-db==2.0.8a0"

```
Successfully built ibm-db

Installing collected packages: ibm-db

Successfully installed ibm-db-2.0.8a0
```